# ESP8266 feather huzzah wiring for MFRC522

Tags: esp8266, adafruit

I'm trying to wire the [mfrc522](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid#id15) and the huzzah but i can't seem to figure out the rst pin.

I found the pin out diagram but it doesn't show or idk how its labeled as.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

use Wemos table from your link. here is the mapping to esp8266 io pins

```
RST/Reset   D3 = io 0
SPI SS      D8 = io 15
SPI MOSI    D7 = io 13
SPI MISO    D6 = io 12
SPI SCK     D5 = io 14
```

If you want, you can use any pin for SS and reset. See the examples.

```
#define SS_PIN 4
#define RST_PIN 5
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);
```

Comment: @xiao-ning-er, did it help?

Answer (score 0):

Use GPIO0 (D3 on the Wemos).  The reset signal is under program control in the library and isn't the same as the ESP8266 reset input.